# Retrieve data on textbox value dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know if this is possible but what I'm trying to accomplish is that when ever I click this link

```
    <a href=?name=$value1 id=$value1 class='txt_value'>Edit</a>
```

> $value1 is a variable of my ID which i retrieved from my database.

my link could be

```
<a href=?name=$value1 id=$value1
<a href=?name=$value2 id=$value2
<a href=?name=$value3 id=$value3
```

etc..

my point is whenever I click any link above, a dialog box(jquery) would appear and insert
$value1 into a textbox inside the dialog box. Question is, is it possible that whenever I click a link all data that is associated with that ID (ex. first name, last name with ID #1 ) would also be called and displayed into that dialog box.

this is my initial code

```
$(".bordered a").click(function(){
$(".ok").val($(this).attr("id"));
$(".create-modal").dialog({
  height: 200,
  modal:true,
  width:300
});

});

<div class="create-modal">
   <input class="ok" type="text"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. The simplest way is to make a ajax request via jQuery to a PHP script which will return a json string. You can get a PHP array and print it via json_encode function to accomplish that. The JQuery function will take care of the json string and convert it into a JavaScript object.